# Osmbonuspack: show elements of visual RadiusMarkerClusterer. How?

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I have a little problem. What I want:

1. Catch a click by cluster. For example, I have personMarkerClusterer. It contains, for example, 3 persons (another person is not in cluster, because distance too big). It's screenshot

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpnWp.png]

I override RadiusMarkerClusterer class, onSingleTapConfirmed method

```
    class MyRadiusMarkerClusterer extends RadiusMarkerClusterer {

    public MyRadiusMarkerClusterer(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {
        if (super.onSingleTapConfirmed(event, mapView)) {
            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "cluster was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

but I get click for any person! If person is not in cluster and I click by him, the method onSingleTapConfirmed calls. Why? I want to get callbacks only for elements of cluster (i.e. by cluster). Yes, it's element of cluster, because we added it by

```
personClusterMarkers.add(marker);
```

by how can I to handle events only for visual cluster?

2. To get list of markers when I click by RadiusMarkerClusterer. We have method getItems() in MarkerClusterer, but it returns all elements. How can I to get only elements of visual cluster?

Answer (score 0):

You overrided onSingleTapConfirmed for MyRadiusMarkerClusterer. So you get answers when anything in the clusterer is clicked.

A clusterer is not a cluster, a clusterer contains many clusters.

If you want to have a customized behaviour when you tap on a cluster marker, you must customize the creation of this cluster marker, by overriding buildClusterMarker.

Have a look here: https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/issues/110

And instead of setting a custom InfoWindow, you will have to set a custom OnMarkerClickListener with marker.setOnMarkerClickListener.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try. I thought that this functionality is already there